# Остановка рекурсии быстрой сортировки массива

Tags: javascript

> Реализовываю тренажер быстрой сортировки массива и визуально вывожу
>   его на экран в браузере.При нажатии кнопки выводится сразу все
>   итерации сортировки .Хотелось бы чтобы при нажатии кнопки делалась
>   только одна итерация, потом нажал еще раз и снова итерация и так. [![На
>   данный момент он выводит вот так][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qZkP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qZkP.png)
>   Как я могу прервать сортировку после каждой итерации и продолжить при нажатии кнопки?

```
function quickSort(items, left, right,) {
    let index;
        if (items.length > 1) {
            index = partition(items, left, right); //index returned from partition
            if (left < index - 1) { //more elements on the left side of the pivot
                    quickSort(items, left, index - 1);
            }
            if (index < right) { //more elements on the right side of the pivot
                    quickSort(items, index, right);
            }
        }
    arr = items;
    return arr;

}

function partition(items, left, right) {
    pivot = items[Math.floor((right + left) / 2)]; //middle element
    let i = left, //left pointer
        j = right; //right pointer

        while (i <= j) {
            while (items[i] < pivot) {
                i++;       //2
            }
            while (items[j] > pivot) {
                j--;  //4
            }
            if (i <= j) {
                if (i == j) {

                    swap(items, i, j); //swapping two elements


                i++;

                j--;
            }

        }

    return i;
}

function swap(items, leftIndex, rightIndex) {
    let temp = items[leftIndex];
    items[leftIndex] = items[rightIndex];
    items[rightIndex] = temp;

    console.log("swap " + swapElOne + " and " + swapElTwo);

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как приложенная картинка соотносится с кодом в вопросе? Код в вопросе вообще приводит к stack overflow если брать массив с картинки

Comment: @Grundy я вытащил основной алгоритм. Все остальное это прорисовка и не более чем. Я  нажимаю кнопку он вырисовывает .КАк я могу сделать его пошагово или заставить его приостановиться пока не будет нажата кнопка

Comment: с текущей реализацией - никак

Comment: а приведенный код вообще работает?

Comment: @Grundy https://dropmefiles.com/FUJ88

Comment: лучше на какой-нить гитхаб или http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue добавь ссылку

Comment: добавлю вечером ответ :)

Comment: @Grundy дружище,можно как то сделать то?Или менять алгоритм надо?

Comment: можно, не дошел вчера :) помогут генераторы :)

Answer (score 2):

Для пошагового выполнения нужно преобразовать алгоритм в стейт-машину, которую как раз можно переводить в соответствующие стейты по клику кнопки. Ручное переделывание может оказаться не тривиальным, однако, JavaScript предоставляет готовую реализацию: [функции-генераторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

В итоге, необходимо изменить только определение функций, чтобы они стали генераторами и расставить [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield), там где нужна остановка, и [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*), там где вызывается внутренняя функция-генератор.

Итог может выглядеть так:

```js
let count_step = 1; //счетчик шагов
let pivot; //опорный элемент
let swapElOne; //перестановочный лемент 1
let swapElTwo; //перестановочный лемент 2

let arr = getArray();
let stop = false;

function getArray() {
  let arr = []; //записываем в этот массив рандомные числа
  let max = 15; // максимальная длина массива
  let rundomnumber; //случайное число
  while (arr.length < max) {
    rundomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); //создадим случайное число
    if (arr.indexOf(rundomnumber) === -1) { // проверим есть оно  у нас или нет
      arr.push(rundomnumber); // записываем в массив т.к нету
    }
  }
  return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
  });
}

function show(arr) { //Вывод массива
  let out = `
    <table class="table table-bordered" id = "arr-table">
      <tr>
        ${arr.map(el => `<td style="background-color:${el === pivot? 'lightcoral': el == swapElOne || el == swapElTwo ?  'lightgreen' : 'transparent'}">${el}</td>`).join('')}
      </tr>
    </table>`;
  $('.arr-output').html(out);
}


function swap(items, leftIndex, rightIndex) {
  let temp = items[leftIndex];
  items[leftIndex] = items[rightIndex];
  items[rightIndex] = temp;
}


function showswap(a, b) { //Показ таблиц
  let out = `Переставляем элементы: ${a} и ${b}<br>`
  $('.text-output').append(out);
  swapElOne = a;
  swapElTwo = b;

}

function showsink(a, b) { //Показ таблиц
  let out = `Сравниваю элементы: ${a} и ${b}<br>`
  $('.text-output').append(out);
}

function choosePivotElement(a) { //Показ таблиц
  let out = `Выбираем опорный элемент: ${a}<br>`
  $('.text-output').append(out);
}

function step() {
  let out = `Шаг ${count_step} :<br>`
  $('.text-output').append(out);
  count_step++;
}

function border() { //Показ таблиц
  let out = `----------------------------------------<br>`
  $('.text-output').append(out);
}

function* quickSort(items, left, right) {
  let index;
  if (items.length > 1) {
    index = yield* partition(items, left, right);
    if (left < index - 1) {
      yield* quickSort(items, left, index - 1);
    }
    if (index < right) { //more elements on the right side of the pivot
      yield* quickSort(items, index, right);
    }
  }
  arr = items;
  return arr;
}

function* partition(items, left, right) {
  pivot = items[Math.floor((right + left) / 2)]; //middle elemen
  let i = left, //left pointer
    j = right; //right pointer

  console.info(items.toString());
  console.log("ВЫбираем опорный элемент " + pivot)

  step();
  choosePivotElement(pivot);
  yield;

  while (i <= j) {
    while (items[i] < pivot) {
      i++; //2
    }
    while (items[j] > pivot) {
      j--; //4
    }

    if (i <= j) {
      if (i == j) {
        step();
        let out = `Подмассив отсортирован<br>`
        $('.text-output').append(out);
        yield;
      } else {
        step();
        // choosePivotElement(pivot);
        showsink(items[i], items[j]);
        showswap(items[i], items[j]);
        show(items);
        yield;
        swap(items, i, j); //sawpping two elements
        show(arr);
        yield;
      }
      i++;

      j--;
    }
    border();
  }
  return i;
}

var qs = quickSort(arr, 0, 14);

function next() {
  console.log(qs.next().done);
}
```

```css
table.table {
  font-family: 'Spartan';
  border: 2px solid #1f7299;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#sort-table {
  font-family: 'Spartan';
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.block-left {
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
}

.block-right {
  width: 600px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.text-output {
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}

.row {
  /*margin-right: 15px;*/
}

tr:hover {
  background: #c9eaf2;
}

td:hover {
  background: #ffc;
}

td:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #cfc;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn-group {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.2.1" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.1.3" rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.1.3" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="popper.js@*" data-semver="1.12.9" src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="block-left">
  <div class="col">
    <br>
    <div class='arr-output'></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block-right">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="text-output">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <button id="next-step" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" onclick="next()" value="continue">Следующий шаг</button>

</div>
```

Comment: можно как-то вернуть чтобы выводилось каждый раз массив для наглядности?

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов, да, просто свой код вывода используй - у тебя .append() был, а я на html() заменил - чтобы тут в экранчик влазило

Comment: большое спасибо!! а тут есть ЛС ,есть кое-какие вопросы по дальнейшей реализации в этом проекте?

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов [Как задать вопрос напрямую участнику Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/440/186999)

Comment: почему этот проект так много жрет ?jочень сильно грузит webstorm .не пойму почему?

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов, не уверен про какой проект ты? какая связь с webstorm если все в браузере выполняется?

Comment: ,да фиг знает почему.Просто когда открываю проект который выше через вэб шторм ,то почему жрет оперативу. А если просто через папку,открываю файл в браузере ,то норм.Ладно посмотрим дальше.
Вот какой у меня вопрос.Я вот сделал демо режим,где пошагово объясняется.Теперь я хочу делать режим контроля . Мне же по сути где то надо хронить шаги и потом их от туда брать.Потом выводить варианты ответов и чтобы пользователь отвечал . Через что мне это лучше реализовать?

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов, не понял вопроса: что за режим контроля? какие шаги и зачем ты хочешь хранить?

Comment: режим контроля представляет собой пошаговый режим.Типа какое действие будет следующем и 4 варианта ответа.Например,на переставить элементв 34 и 56  и вырианты ответов какое действие нужно выполнить.